# Given non-interactive zero-knowledge proofs as a primitive, wouldn't signatures be easily implemented with hashes?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Assume a working non-interactive zero-knowledge proof implementation. Would a public key signature scheme implemented as this work:

1. Bob picks a random `a`, his private key, and broadcasts `A = H(a)`, his public key.
2. Bob broadcasts `sig : ∃ a . H(a) == A && H(a | 0 | msg) == B)`, `msg, B : {0,1}*`.
3. Alice verifies `sig` using zk-snarks to convince herself Bob signed `msg`.

? If so, am I right to think an implementation of non-interactive zero-knowledge proofs with satisfactory characteristics (i.e., no trusted setup, fast and reducible to a known hard problem) would provide an easy replacement for most existing cryptographic techniques?

Comment: Note that when msg is empty, B will be the public key. ​ ​ ​ Are you sure you don't want to replace `a | msg` with `a | 0 | msg`? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Also, do you really mean to switch from asking about zk-snarks to asking about ZKPs? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer doesn't that just mean one isn't able to sign the empty message?

Comment: Well, _if the construction didn't say anything about it and the zk-SNARK is malleable_, then that would let the adversary _forge_ a signature of the empty message. ​ (Specifying that the empty message is not part of the message-space would indeed fix the problem.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Interesting, good catch.

Comment: Zero-Knowledge Proofs ​ (as well as [arguments](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/ZKsymmetric-eurocrypt.pdf)) ​ are usually interactive. ​ ​ ​ Did you mean to instead change to asking about [NIZK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-interactive_zero-knowledge_proof) protocols? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: But... you asked me to change to ZKPs...

Comment: No, I just pointed out that you had been asking about different things. ​ I expected you to change to zk-snarks. ​ (However, thinking about that now, I re-recall that, if [PRGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator) exist then NIZK _must_ involve trusted setup.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer "if PRGs exist then NIZK must involve trusted setup." sounds interesting. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @CodesInChaos : ​ I don't, but I [just wrote it up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293100/232555). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Guys BTW, this question was left unanswered. I think this is a pretty easy question to answer. Basically I'm asking if I'm right on my intuition that zk-snarks are such a breakthrough for cryptography. The concept honestly seems miraculous as most of everything else can be seen as a special case of zk-snarks, it seems.